# Children of a Scene not releasing fast enough?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

Have a couple of child nodes in a scene, and do a quick transition to a new scene.

In the new scene, `didMove(to view: ….)` is used to add the children from the previous scene to this next scene.

SceneKit crashes when doing this quickly, seemingly because the children of the old scene haven’t yet been released.

***If I add a slight delay before adding the children to the second scene, it’s fine… it seems SpriteKit isn’t releasing the child fast enough for the scene transition.***

*the above is the most important thing to understand with regard the purpose for this question. I (wrongly) assumed SpriteKit would make sure all nodes attached to a scene were released before attempting to add them to a subsequent scene. It doesn't do this. But it does release them, it just takes a little time. Is this one frame? One second? Dunno...*

**My scene transition time is 0.25 seconds**

Also tried using `willMove(to view: ….)` in the original scene to manually remove the children. This also doesn’t work, seemingly same behaviour: not fast enough.

Also tried assuming the child still has a relationship to its parent, so tried moving to its new parent, the new scene, with `move(toParent:…)` this also crashes. So maybe the children are already flagged as about to be released, I suppose.

Is this known about, and if so, how is it dealt with?

Comment: Can't you add the children to the scene *before* moving to it? I would think that would give the fastest results.

Comment: So remove from one, then add, then switch scene?

Comment: argh, this is an interesting approach. I've just figured out how `moveTo(` actually works.... it's not ideal and pure enough for this situation. But could be used in other situations.

Comment: You always want to preload as much as possible to reduce loading times (such as didMoveToView). I can't specifically say why you are getting crashes without your project files.. Can you can reproduce the situation consistently (such as presenting a bug) in a new project?

Comment: I'm working in a skeleton project to create the menus, so yes... it's completely reproducible, and the steps in the question show my attempts at isolating and determining the problem.

Comment: Cool. Post the project on GitHub (or email me) because I'm interested in seeing this as well (it may be a big problem for me at some point too).

Comment: @Confused `didMove` in the new scene gets called before the old scene dies, because in a transition both must exist.  It actually gets called right after you present the scene

Comment: I would recommend just using .copy() when you are adding nodes to the new scene, unless you have some crazy nodes that may not work correctly (like `SKEmitterNode`)

Comment: @Confused if you provided more details on the crash I could help you out.  moveParent is a reference move, not a copy move, so nothing is getting retained / released.  This would mean there is something goofy going on that you may have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't present a scene and have `willMove` function at the same time in the same frame (SK loop)--your next scene's `viewDidLoad` will be called before the previous scene is destroyed. You have to remove all of the nodes before calling `presentScene`:

I suggest making a global variable of some sort to access your `SKView`; with that you can have control over your scenes from anywhere:

```
currentScene.removeAllChildren()
gView!.presentScene(nextScene)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129462/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-confused).

Answer (score 0):

> **“Is this a known about, and if so, how is it dealt with?"**

**Yes**, this is a known issue of the SceneKit and IOS design and operational paradigms. It is considered that a scene must always be present and upon the screen. Can't have time without a scene onscreen.

As a result, for a brief time during transitions, both scenes are loaded, and active.

### *There are three ways to do deal with this problem:*

- Remove all content from the old scene prior to executing the transition so it can be instantly loaded by the new scene in `didMove(to view...`

  or
- Wait for completion of the transition before loading any content from the old scene into the new scene so there's no ownership conflicts of children.

  or
- KnightOfDragon’s first suggestion to use `.copy()` so there’s not the same instances being fought over by the scenes.

Comment: or you could load all of the content before moving to the next scene, as I first suggested. Or, in the next scene's transition you could remove everything before it deallocs. So that is at least 5 ways.

Comment: ... or just not deal with a global design pattern hahaha

Comment: @Knight0fDragon how does non global world look and work?

Comment: I dunno, it would take a lot of work I am guessing,  I need to see your code.

Comment: That's what I think about most "correct" OOP practices... a LOT of work. How do I find your email address?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon do you know anything about making custom transitions? Given that the two scenes exist in memory at the same time, during a transition, is it possible to make a long "official" transition, and then do customisation of the transition by influencing nodes in both scenes with motion and transparency, etc?